# What is meaning "that's the whole day gone"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In movies, I hear a  lot of "that's the whole day gone."

Now I want to know what is meaning exactly?

Before this sentence, they talk about eat tea.

I search in google and I don't find anything!

I think meaning is "Fatigue goes away"?!

Comment: A direct quote would be nice. "That's the whole day gone" means that entire day has  passed and could imply that the time hasn't been sufficient to complete a task.  *Tea* is an afternoon meal in England, but as context is everything, you'll have to give us more.

Comment: Nothing to do with fatigue. Tea is what some British people call their _early evening_ meal, so it could imply "We've wasted a whole day and achieved nothing".